# Return GeoJSON from a Census Tract

Tags: postgis, geojson, google-maps, geocoding, tiger

I am working on a new project where I need to highlight census tracts by boundaries. Google Maps can do this as long as I give it GeoJSON (data layers).

I did some research and it seemed like Tiger is a good solution. I was able to install and setup PostGIs and a Tiger Geocoder database (125 gigabytes!) https://postgis.net/docs/Extras.html

After going through this incredibly long process, I could finally geocode an address using the built-in function geocode. I could even return back GeoJSON from an address:

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(geomout) 
FROM geocode('8615 Chestnut Oak Rd, Baltimore, MD 21234', 1)
```

and it spits out GeoJSON:

**{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-76.5617440647409,39.3951950048467]}**

Finally, using the *get_tract* function, I can get back a census tract like this:

```
SELECT get_tract(geomout, 'tract_id') As tract_id 
FROM geocode('8615 Chestnut Oak Rd, Baltimore, MD 21234', 1) 
As g;`
```

Which returns a tract.

**The Question:**

Now that I've shown what I've been able to do, what I can't do is get the GeoJSON for this tract. Would anyone be able to nudge me in the right direction?

I am wondering if maybe there is a function to return back a geometry object from a census tract (which I can then pass into the ST_AsGeoJSON function, or some other solution).

Answer (score 3):

You could use [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org) to handle the conversion of PostGIS results to [GeoJSON](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/outputformats.html) for you. A simple WFS request like this would return the geometry (and optionally the attributes associated with it).

```
http://astun-desktop:8080/geoserver/wfs?request=GetFeature&typeName=topp:states&propertyName=STATE_NAME,LAND_KM,the_geom&CQL_FILTER=contains(the_geom, POINT(-76.5617440647409 39.3951950048467)&version=1.0.0&outputformat=json
```

Comment: This is interesting, thanks. Let me take a look i'll let you know if I have any issues.

Answer (score 1):

So it appears there is a 'tract' table that has a column called the_geom.
 You can simply pass this value into ST_AsGeoJSON() and it will work, giving you the polygon represented as GeoJSON. That's all there was to it. Not sure how I missed this!

Answer (score 0):

I've translated most of Census' Cartography files to GeoJSON and made them available here:

https://github.com/loganpowell/census-geojson